# How to be up-to-date with master and have the old committed files in the branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab

I am new to **git** and I need help. I checked similar questions and tried many solutions told in that questions but I couldn't find a solution to my case.

**Case :** I should work with a `branch` which was created in the past. The last couple of `commits` in this `branch` have classes that I should write my code into and also other necessary code. `Merge request` of this `branch` into `master` is reverted by admin at that time in the **gitlab**.

In the meantime, a lot of `commits` have been merged into `master`.

Now I should be up-to-date with `master` and I should have the files created in the past in this `branch`. 
When I merge `master` into this `branch`, files in this branch is deleted.

What I do:

I **checkout** `master`. I am up-to-date with remote master.

I **checkout** `branch`. I am up-to-date with remote branch.

I **merge** `master`.

Now I am still in my local branch and merged master. Files in the banch which I need are deleted after the merge.

What should be done to have the current master and all needed files in the branch at the same time in this case? I would be grateful with your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good place to use `rebase`. Rebase is done to pull the new changes from a parent branch from which a child branch was forked. After some time the parent branch might have had new changes. `rebase` command will pull the latest changes from the parent branch and will re-aplly the work done on the child branch.

You can read about git-rebase at the git documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sid-m . I tried rebase but this didn't solve the issue. I noticed that it is because merge request of the branch was reverted in the master after it had been merged. So after merging master into my branch, I reverted the revert and problem is solved.Your answer helped me to learn though.